# How to add HighCharts bundle to BundleConfig? MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I've added the High Charts API to an MVC 3 application, but the reference to the HighChart bundle shows as directory not found.

I created a reference to the bundle in the BundleConfig class:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highcharts").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Content","*.js"));
```

Does anyone know how to correct the bundle specification and reference?

Throws a directory not found exception:

[image: exception]

Location of the HighChart's jquery folder:

[image: high chart bundle]

Comment: You're adding the `/scripts/content/` folder to the bundle, yet the screenshot you've added shows the scripts in `/scripts/highcharts-4.0.1/`. You need to specify the correct path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the `.IncludeDirectory("~/scripts/content)` to `.IncludeDirectory("~/scripts/highcharts-4.0.1", "*.js")`

or `.IncludeDirectory("~/scripts/highcharts-4.0.1", "*.js", true)` if you want to add the .js in the subdirectories of highcharts-4.0.1 too

And you will add the correct path to highcharts in your bundle

Comment: so I've changed the bundle to:  `            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highcharts").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.1/js", "*.js"));
`

Comment: But I still get an error in the rendered page: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined`

Comment: You must have something like ` bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/highcharts").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Highcharts-4.0.‌​1/js", "*.js"));` in your bundleconfig and `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/highcharts")` in your view